# JSON.parse error with nodejs v0.6.12 on ubuntu

Tags: json, node.js

I just installed nodejs v0.6.12 on Ubuntu 10 on Amazon AWS.
The code runs without any issues on my computer (running 0.6.11 on ubuntu) but on the AWS server, I get a JSON parse error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
    at Object.parse (native)

The error appears to be coming from the line where I am trying to parse the request from the client (containing a JSON array).  It does not appear that I am using any unassigned variable in the line where the error appears to be coming from.

Once again, the code works on my computer - I do not believe I should need any modules for JSON since its built-in with nodejs.  Any help in troubleshooting will be appreciated.

The line throwing the error is given below:

obj = JSON.parse(req.rawBody);  // I tried both - first by assigning obj an empty value
var obj = JSON.parse(req.rawBody); //

Thanks.

Comment: Wait, let me guess. The client is written in Python.

Comment: thanks for responding.  The client side information is coming from jquery/javascript.  I am not using Python - appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the new version of Express (3.0) does not appear to support req.rawBody anymore - the old version did.